# Why don't my observables properly emit with the async pipe and *ngIf in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am following along on a tutorial on Udemy about authentication.  It's a little older, so I'm not 100% that one of the things that it is showing me is correct anymore -- mainly because it isn't working.  :-)

**Problem:** The observables that are supposed to be tracking if a user is logged in are apparently always undefined, because the Register/Login/Logout menu items are always all **not** showing.

There's an authentication server that looks like the following:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private rootURL: string = 'https://localhost:3000/users';

  private subject: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(undefined);
  user$: Observable<User> = this.subject.asObservable().pipe(filter(user => !!user));
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean> = this.user$.pipe(map(user => !!user.id));
  isLoggedOut$: Observable<boolean> = this.user$.pipe(map(isLoggedIn => !!isLoggedIn));

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {httpClient.get<User>(`${this.rootURL}`)
              .subscribe(user => this.subject.next(user ? user : UNDEFINED_USER));}

  login(userName: string, password: string) {...}

  register(userName: string, password: string): Observable<User> {...}

  logout() {...}
}
```

then, I have the following component that should display the Register/Login/Logout menu items appropriately.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {}

  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;
  isLoggedOut$: Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.auth.isLoggedIn$;
    this.isLoggedOut$ = this.auth.isLoggedOut$;
  }

  logout() {...}
}
```

and here is the corresponding template portion:

```
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" *ngIf="isLoggedOut$ | async" routerLink="/register">Register</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" *ngIf="isLoggedOut$ | async" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" style="cursor: pointer;" *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
  </div>
```

UNDEFINED_USER is defined as follows:

```
export const UNDEFINED_USER: User = {
  id: '',
  email: ''
};
```

So the problem is that all three of the `*ngIf` statement above always evaluate to `false` and the three items are always hidden.

The chaining of the Observable fields like that seems really strange to me -- is that supposed to still work, or is there now a better way?

What is the right way to do this?

**EDIT**: Added `.id` to the `map` call on `IsLoggedIn$``

**EDIT**: Added definition of UNDEFINED_USER

Comment: Hint: your `user$` observable **doesn't emit** if `user` is false-y (therefore `isLoggedOut$` will also never emit true and will only ever emit false and also it won't emit until the user has been logged in).

Comment: Do you call `this.subject.next(...)` at some point?

Comment: @ConnorsFan  Yes, I am. I updated the constructor to show that.  I also call it when a user is registered and when one logs in....

Comment: For a test, you could subscribe to your observables in `NavbarComponent.ngOnInit()` and use `console.log` to check if the expected values were emitted.

Comment: @ConnorsFan -- good idea, thanks. Interestingly, the event never fires!  That would certainly explain things......

Comment: Firstly: your observables are filtered by this operator `.pipe(filter(user => !!user))`, secondly: `isLoggedIn$` and `isLoggedOut$` emit the same value

Comment: What's the value of `UNDEFINED_USER`?

Comment: @yurzui -- edited the question to include it.

Comment: You could also add a `console.log` in `httpClient.get<User>().subscribe(...)` to check if `this.subject.next` is called. Maybe an error occurs during the `get`.

Comment: You can try this logic `user$: Observable<User> = this.subject.asObservable().pipe(filter(user => !!user));
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean> = this.user$.pipe(map(user => !!user.id));
  isLoggedOut$: Observable<boolean> = this.user$.pipe(map(user => !user.id)); ` Demo https://ng-run.com/edit/88ykRgOuMSKYxYt96p4S?open=app%2Fauth.service.ts

Comment: @yurzui  thank you for the help.  Alas, that didn't seem to change the behavior in my app.

Comment: @ConnorsFan  I added the console calls as you suggested, and the values for IsLoggedIn$ and isLoggedOut$ never change

Comment: I updated example https://ng-run.com/edit/88ykRgOuMSKYxYt96p4S?open=app%2Fauth.service.ts You can click on `Login` and you will be logged in. And vise versa, click on 'Logout' to log out.

Comment: @yurzui  --Thank you for your efforts.